# Adding row to end of tableview with animation dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView that begins completely empty, and as a user enters data and presses a "save" button a new cell needs to be added to the tableview. I have this working totally fine by adding the new data to my data array and calling [tableView reloadData], but I would like to use an animation for when the new cell is added. Im assuming I will need to use some of the tableView editing methods.

A cell needs to be added WITH animation every time "save" is pressed always to the bottom of the table view (always after the last row). I'm running into problems because my table is initially empty so I have  no indexPath to the last row.

This is my attempt:

```
NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
NSInteger lastRowIndex = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[pathToLastRow] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Is it only not working for the case where the table is empty?

Comment: Yea.. but its also not working when I add a new cell it takes the data from the previous cell and adds that to the table, so I am always one cell behind.. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I think it's an indexing issue, modified my answer a couple times but try the current code that's in right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try..

```
NSInteger lastSectionIndex = MAX(0, [self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1);
NSInteger lastRowIndex = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex];
NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];
```

Comment: No, I made that change and removed the -1... that worked! But the animation isn't happening at all now

Comment: even if you're only replacing the top 3 lines with these 3 lines and keeping your bottom 4 lines of code?

Comment: Okay its working properly now! Thank you, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You insertion index should be numbersOfRows without the -1
Remove the `[self.tableView reloadData]` line and you should also be sure your numbersOfRows method return a numbersOfRow + 1 at the end of your method.

Comment: its crashing because the pathToLastRow is nil when the tableview is empty. It never even gets there.. I could just simply make an if condition for if the table is empty which I tried and it did not work properly.

Comment: Remove the -1 when you calculate the index.

Comment: Thanks that did work! But its not doing an animation

Comment: Did you removed the reloadData line?

Comment: The problem was being caused by the -1, and the animation wasn't happening I think because I was using UITableViewRowAnimationBottom, switching it to UITableViewRowAnimationTop did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Right, you needed the -1 for the section index because you wanted the last section, but you didn't want the -1 for the row index because you wanted the last row + 1.

And the section index needs a safe-check to not be -1 in case there are no sections, hence the MAX(..,..)